# on the iOS slider, can I click anywhere on the scale or do I have to drag the slider knob around?

Tags: android, ios, slider, drag, uislider

I am trying to make the iOS slider as similar as possible to the Android one. One main difference is that on Android, if you click anywhere on the slider scale, the slider knob will jump to that position, while iOS it seems that you can only drag it to a position. Is there anyway to fix this?
I would like to do it using objective-C (which I am new to) and I'm not quite sure where to start. I understand the code used to store the slider value, but not how to change the method in which that value is obtained.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The main idea is that you need to detect when the slider is being clicked on, and where it is clicked within the slider's boundary.

So if you can detect the x position of the click with respect to the slider's frame, then just divide it by the width of your slider, then you get a ratio of where it is inside the frame. Multiply with your max value of your slider and you are done.

Notes for implementation:
There are various ways to detect touches within a view. The easiest is just to overlay it with an UIButton. A more concise way is to subclass UISlider and use the touch events `touchStarted`, `touchMoved`, `touchEnded` to determine specific behaviour. You can find their specs in UIView's class documents.

Once you determine the new slider value based on your calculations, just set it using `setValue:` method.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But the problem i'm facing is not where in the slider frame I clicked, but rather where on the slider scale (Slider bar). Instead of having the knob dragged along the scale, I want to be able to click anywhere on the scale and have the knob jump to that position.

Comment: I believe slider frame and the actual scale is related by a constant. So perhaps when you detected your touch's x position, make it x - 20 or something until it looks right? I'm not sure if the actual offset is documented - it might be though.

Comment: I'll look for that. This will hopefully point me in the right direction, and I'll come back here if I get an answer. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Oh I just found it! This would give you the exact frame of the track. Just pass in the bound of the slider.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISlider_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UISlider/trackRectForBounds:

Comment: I'm thinking of using the setValue method from this class, not sure how it will end up though. It makes sense what you said, about saving the location of where I click; then if I could use setValue to move the slider knob if that makes sense

Comment: That's how it should work in theory! Make sure you use the width of the track rect though! Hopefully you learned some new stuff from doing this :)